# Express routes doesn't work

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm doing a web page with the express generator, I have three pages in jade, but when I want to go from one to another it shows me this mistake:

```
Error: Not Found
at app.use.res.render.message (F:\NodeJSPortable\Data\letstalksaku\app.js:39:13)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (F:\NodeJSPortable\Data\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (F:\NodeJSPortable\Data\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
at F:\NodeJSPortable\Data\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (F:\NodeJSPortable\Data\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
at next (F:\NodeJSPortable\Data\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
at SendStream.error (F:\NodeJSPortable\Data\node_modules\express\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:120:7)
at SendStream.emit (events.js:95:17)
at SendStream.error (F:\NodeJSPortable\Data\node_modules\express\node_modules\send\index.js:245:17)
at SendStream.onStatError (F:\NodeJSPortable\Data\node_modules\express\node_modules\send\index.js:356:12)
```

This is the code from app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https'),
http = require('http');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var index2 = require('./routes/index2');    
var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

require('./routes')(app);
module.exports = app;

https.createServer({key: privateKey, cert: certificate}, app).listen(8000);
http.createServer(app).listen(8001);

console.log('running on https://localhost:8000 and http://localhost:8001');
```

My jade files just have this code

```
doctype html
html
head
body
a#Boton1(href='/index2') Crea tu sala
```

I just can't find the mistake, would you please help me

Comment: Unrelated, but I thought Jade was indentation-based?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Express.js 4 routes not matching with router.route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111220/express-js-4-routes-not-matching-with-router-route)

Comment: expand upon this: `require('./routes')(app);`